# MySQL enum vs. set

Tags: mysql, database

For MySQL Data type of "enum" and "set" what are the differences and advantages and disadvantages of using one versus the other?

Example data type:

- enum('A', 'B', 'C')
- set('A', 'B', 'C')

The only difference that I am aware of is that ENUM only allows one value to be selected versus SET allows multiple values to be selected.

Comment: No adv/disadv. You should choose one of them depending on your requirements.

Comment: The two types are unrelated. You might as well ask which is better - int or text?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-enum.html) states:

> Definition of a ENUM or SET column does act as a constraint on values
>   entered into the column. An error occurs for values that do not
>   satisfy these conditions:
>
> An ENUM value must be one of those listed in the column definition, or
>   the internal numeric equivalent thereof. The value cannot be the error
>   value (that is, 0 or the empty string). For a column defined as
>   ENUM('a','b','c'), values such as '', 'd', or 'ax' are illegal and are
>   rejected.
>
> A SET value must be the empty string or a value consisting only of the
>   values listed in the column definition separated by commas. For a
>   column defined as SET('a','b','c'), values such as 'd' or 'a,b,c,d'
>   are illegal and are rejected.

Comment: NOTE! A value of `(a, b, c, d)` will not be rejected. Just the `d` will be rejected thus resulting in the value `(a, b, c)`.

Comment: This might be the official documentation, but it is still a very confusing way of describing them. Based on other answers the difference becomes clear. SET is an array of ENUM, where each value consists of 0 or more enum style values.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Clear explanation of differences and dis/advantages was asked for; the official documentation, of which this answer is a mere copy, fails doing so.

Comment: (a, b, c, d) will be rejected if Strict mode is on

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: MySQL documentation anyone can search google, what's the use of copy pasting some documentation without contributing something original?

Answer (score 285):

analogy:
ENUM = radio fields (only accepted values are those listed, may only choose one)
SET = checkbox fields (only accepted values are those listed, may choose multiple)

Comment: kya baat hai. simple explanation

Answer (score 48):

Enum and Set totally depends on requirements, like if you have a list of radio button where only one can be chosen at a time, use Enum. And if you have a list of checkbox  where at a time more then one item can be chosen, use set.

Answer (score 27):

```
CREATE TABLE setTest(
  attrib SET('bold','italic','underline')
);

INSERT INTO setTest (attrib) VALUES ('bold');
INSERT INTO setTest (attrib) VALUES ('bold,italic');
INSERT INTO setTest (attrib) VALUES ('bold,italic,underline');
```

You can copy the code above and paste it in mysql, and you will find that **SET** actually is a collection. You can store each combine of attributes you declare.

```
CREATE TABLE enumTest(
 color ENUM('red','green','blue')
);

INSERT INTO enumTest (color) VALUES ('red');
INSERT INTO enumTest (color) VALUES ('gray');
INSERT INTO enumTest (color) VALUES ('red,green');
```

You can also copy the code above. And you will find that each **ENUM** actually can only be store once each time. And you will find that the results of last 2 lines will both be empty.

Answer (score 12):

Actually it's pretty simple:

When you define an **ENUM('Yes', 'No', 'Maybe')** then you **must** INSERT only one of these values (or their positional index number)

When you define a **SET('R', 'W', 'X')** then you **can** INSERT an empty string, **or** one or more of these values. If you insert something that's not in the predefined set, an empty string is is inserted instead. Note that before inserting all duplicate values are discarded, so only one instance of each permitted value is being inserted.

Hope this clears it up.

Please note that Winbobob's answer is incorrect and  contains flawed examples, as when inserting multiple values, the values must be strings, separated with commas. All his inserts are actually inserting just a single value (and last two aren't in the defined set)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's wrong in Winbobob's answer. Maybe you misunderstood it.

Comment: Respectfully, I and 11 other upvote[r]s would like to disagree with you.

Comment: Respectfully I'd like to ask you whether you thought about that those upvotes could be about your other paragraphs? Also, I don't see any respect in ignoring my question.

Comment: Your question? Where?

Answer (score 1):

ENUM --> choose only one of the available values to insert.

(no_null, no_any_duplicate)

---

SET  --> choose any combination or single value like a set  and insert them into.

(null, individual_values,    all_the_available_values_together)

Answer (score 1):

I addition to the points already mentioned in the answers so far given I am adding an additional point on the difference -

MySQL stores ENUM string values internally as decimal integers of values 1 through n for a column with n members in the enumeration.

MySQL represents SET string values as a bitmap using one bit per value, thus the values are stored internally as 1, 2, 4, 8, ..... up to 65,535 for a maximum of 64 members.

This point is demonstrated as below -

**ENUM example -**

I create table `table1` with column `col1` having data type of `ENUM('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')` with the following table structure -

```
| table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` enum('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

`col1` gets internally stored as follows -

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | element | decimal_value |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 | a       |             1 |
|  2 | b       |             2 |
|  3 | c       |             3 |
|  4 | d       |             4 |
|  5 | e       |             5 |
|  6 | f       |             6 |
|  7 | g       |             7 |
|  8 | h       |             8 |
|  9 | i       |             9 |
| 10 | j       |            10 |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

Now, suppose we want to insert the value - `'e'` into `col1`

`'e'` has the index `5`

Thus to enter `'e'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (1, 5);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | e    |
+----+------+
```

and we see that in first row we have the value of `col1` as `'e'`

Again, suppose we want to insert the value - `'i'` into `col1`

`'i'` has the index `9`

Thus to enter `'i'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (2, 9);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | e    |
|  2 | i    |
+----+------+
```

and we see that in second row we have the value of `col1` as `'i'`

Again, suppose we want to insert the value - `'a'` into `col1`

`'a'` has the index `1`

Thus to enter `'a'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (3, 1);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | e    |
|  2 | i    |
|  3 | a    |
+----+------+
```

and we see that in third row we have the value of `col1` as `'a'`

---

**SET example -**

I create table `table1` with column `col1` having data type of `SET('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')` with the following table structure -

```
| table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` set('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

`col1` gets internally stored as follows -

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
| id | element | binary_value   | decimal_value |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|  1 | a       | 0000 0000 0001 |             1 |
|  2 | b       | 0000 0000 0010 |             2 |
|  3 | c       | 0000 0000 0100 |             4 |
|  4 | d       | 0000 0000 1000 |             8 |
|  5 | e       | 0000 0001 0000 |            16 |
|  6 | f       | 0000 0010 0000 |            32 |
|  7 | g       | 0000 0100 0000 |            64 |
|  8 | h       | 0000 1000 0000 |           128 |
|  9 | i       | 0001 0000 0000 |           256 |
| 10 | j       | 0010 0000 0000 |           512 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
```

Now, suppose we want to insert the value - `'e,f,i'` into `col1`

Then the binary_value of `'e,f,i'` is calculated by adding binary_values of `'e'`, `'f'` and `'i'` which is `0001 0011 0000` and corresponding decimal_value is `304` as shown below -

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
| id | element | binary_value   | decimal_value |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|  5 | e       | 0000 0001 0000 |            16 |
|  6 | f       | 0000 0010 0000 |            32 |
|  9 | i       | 0001 0000 0000 |           256 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|    | e,f,i   | 0001 0011 0000 |           304 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
```

Thus to enter `'e,f,i'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (1, 304);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+
| id | col1  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | e,f,i |
+----+-------+
```

and we see that in first row we have the value of `col1` as `'e,f,i'`

Again, suppose we want to insert the value - `'a,j'` into `col1`

Then the binary_value of `'a,j'` is calculated by adding binary_values of `'a'` and `'j'` which is `0010 0000 0001` and corresponding decimal_value is `513` as shown below -

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
| id | element | binary_value   | decimal_value |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|  1 | a       | 0000 0000 0001 |             1 |
| 10 | j       | 0010 0000 0000 |           512 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|    | a,j     | 0010 0000 0001 |           513 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
```

Thus to enter `'a,j'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (2, 513);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+
| id | col1  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | e,f,i |
|  2 | a,j   |
+----+-------+
```

and we see that in second row we have the value of `col1` as `'a,j'`

Again, suppose we want to insert the value - `'b,d,h,i'` into `col1`

Then the binary_value of `'b,d,h,i'` is calculated by adding binary_values of `'b'`, `'d'`, `'h'` and `'i'` which is `0001 1000 1010` and corresponding decimal_value is `394` as shown below -

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
| id | element | binary_value   | decimal_value |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|  2 | b       | 0000 0000 0010 |             2 |
|  4 | d       | 0000 0000 1000 |             8 |
|  8 | h       | 0000 1000 0000 |           128 |
|  9 | i       | 0001 0000 0000 |           256 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
|    | b,d,h,i | 0001 1000 1010 |           394 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------+
```

Thus to enter `'b,d,h,i'` into `col1` we use the following query -

```
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (3, 394);
```

Then we check the values present in `table1` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+---------+
| id | col1    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | e,f,i   |
|  2 | a,j     |
|  3 | b,d,h,i |
+----+---------+
```

and we see that in third row we have the value of `col1` as `'b,d,h,i'`