# Best practice for fixed number of strings in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

Say i have a datatype called "status" as a row in a mysql table. Status can only be a fixed number of strings, say "active", "inactive" and "pending". What datatype is best practice to use?

- Make another table "statuses" and have an pointer id in my table?
- Make a php array containing the different statuses and use my status-row as index for the array?
- Simply letting status be a string containing the current status?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use an `ENUM`? Input/output is strings, but it can only be a specific set of values (and it saves it in a much better way than eg. `VARCHAR`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set of statuses is fixed at development time you definitely want to use [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html). Another case is when possible statuses can be added in runtime. In this case you want to use separated table to store them and foreign key to check that all statuses are valid.

Using simple string for this is a kind of bad practice. E.g. just a minor misspelling in status can break everything related to the particular row.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically for exactly that purpose is the ENUM type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    status ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'pending')
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is not sufficient for just 3 non-changable values .

For limited and fixed number of strings use `SET` type like this :

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `status` SET( 'active', 'insactive', 'pending' ) NOT NULL
```

and for check the value of a field you can have access to them by their name

`('active', 'insactive', 'pending')` or even numbers `( 1 , 2 , 3 )` .

For example if the value of a filed is **active** :

```
if($value=="active") //returns TRUE
if($value== 1) //returns TRUE too
```

Comment: [A `SET` can also include an empty value (which might not be wanted) - an `ENUM` cannot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14798525/247893)

Comment: what about `NOT NULL` then ?

Comment: Do you know that your `status` field can contain something like 'active,inactive' if it's `SET`? It's strange to allow it. Why `SET` is better than `ENUM`?

Answer (score -1):

You may follow any of the three options you proposed plus you may use ENUM.

I'd avoid option number 1.

I'd go (but it's a matter of coding style and preference) with option nr. 3. Store the value as a string, with the fields with fixed size, like char with size of 16...